# What is the meaning of "emerging science" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The technique of concept mapping was developed by Joseph D. Novak and
>   his research team at Cornell University in the 1970s as a means of
>   representing the **emerging science** knowledge of students.

What is the meaning of "emerging science" in this context?

Comment: emerging science-knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be parsing the phrase "emerging science knowledge" as `[[emerging science]knowledge]`, when you should actually be parsing it `[emerging [science knowledge]]` in this case.

In other words, what is emerging is the knowledge of science, rather than knowledge about emerging (i.e. new) science.